# IE9 CSS precedence... bug?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, operator-precedence

I have two CSS rules:

```
.avo-lime-table th,
.avo-lime-table td {  
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Rule two

```
.avo-lime {
  background-color: green; 
}
```

Everything works fine in FireFox, Chrome, Opera and Safari. Obviously Microsoft's browser (as always) has some diffrent ideas about rendering my page...

```
<div class="avo-center-shrink">
  <form method="post" action="/someformAction">
    <table class="avo-lime-table">
      <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col>
      </colgroup>
      <thead>
        <tr><th colspan="2" class="avo-lime">Login form heading here</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr><td colspan="2">submit button here</td>
      </tr></tfoot>    
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="avo-lime-h unselectable" scope="row">Login:</th>
          <td class="avo-light-h">login input here</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

In above code I've skipped a few 's that are not importaint for this example.

How it should look (Firefox):

[image: How it should look (Firefox)]

How it looks (IE9):

[image: How it looks (IE9)]

## Why is the first rule more specific (to IE) than the second one?

How can I fix that in IE? I've tried diffrent things:

```
**.avo-lime, .avo-lime-table th.avo-lime** { background-color: darkgreen; // fallback background color
 //here some gradients }
```

but It does not work!

## EDIT:

OK, it seems that I had to clear browser cache twice, becouse for some reason it did not update CSS file after the first time.

So all answers that **avo-lime-table th** is more specific than **.avo-lime** were true, and changeing it to **th.avo-lime** did the trick.

I'm gonna give everyone a +1 and mark answered the first correct answer.

Comment: Did you try using !Important?

Comment: @AshwinSingh stop proposing such nonsense. @ loostro Post your css please. Most likey you have an error in your code.

Comment: If I use IE9 Developer tools and "disable" .avo-lime-table th rule, then .avo-lime rule is being applied to the element. So it's not a problem of wrong CSS inside the rule, but it's basically about rule precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To your actual problem:** remove

```
filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
```

and it will work just fine in IE9.

**About the css-rule precedence:**

The rule

```
.avo-lime-table th
```

has higher precedence than

```
.avo-lime
```

because it contains a class selector and an element selector which is higher than only one class selector. This is not only true for IE but in all other browser too.

To give it a higher precedence change it to

```
th.avo-lime
```

Now both rules have the same specificity, but the second rule overrides the first rule by simple cascading (rules declared later in the stylesheet override previous ones)

Read more about [css selector specificity](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) to understand this complicated matter.

Comment: i did try th.avo-lime - didn't change anything

Comment: update: it seems my browser cache did not clear correctly and i had to do it manually - the second time your solution (th.avo-lime) worked, thx

Answer (score 2):

There is something not quite right about your question.

The css rule:

```
.avo-lime { ...
```

Needs to be

```
th.avo-lime { ...
```

If you want it to take precedence over the other rule. But this is the case in Firefox too.

Here is the [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/nnCKJ/) you can remove the leading `th` from `th.avo-lime` to see this in Firefox.

Comment: .avo-lime, th.avo-lime { and here rules } does not change anything

Comment: update: it seems my browser cache did not clear correctly and i had to do it manually - the second time your solution (th.avo-lime) worked, thx

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be disabling the gradient, then wondering why it's not showing a gradient.

If that's not the case, then the answer is because `.avo-lime-table td` is more specific than `.avo-lime`, and so takes precedence.

Comment: update: it seems my browser cache did not clear correctly and i had to do it manually - the second time, after clearing cache your solution (th.avo-lime) worked, thx

Answer (score 1):

I tried that on my PC

Just remove `filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);`

that because its override previous property `filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#46ae0e', endColorstr='#a5e54b', GradientType=0);`

Comment: thats not the problem, the rules in .avo-lime are not applied becouse .avo-lime-table th takes precedence

Comment: @loostro try that first, its working with me :) but note that will as you to enable blocked content.

Comment: @loostro, will ask you* (fix for my previous comment), so enable the blocked content.

Answer (score 0):

Note that what you are doing with your `background-image` rules is not setting the background image depending on the browser, but each now `background-image` row overwrites the one defined previously. The reason the background works in every browser except IE is that the other browsers.

To make sure the `ms-` rule applies in IE, you should add

```
.avo-lime {
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #46ae0e, #a5e54b 85%);
}
```

to a css file or `<style>` tag that loads after this one and load it only when IE is the client's browser with the help of your server-side script language or with the help of conditional comments (note: I heard the latter will not be supported anymore starting from IE10).

Comment: my css is based on twitter bootstrap's button css https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css#L2590