# IE9 Order of Precedence with background-color

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I'm having trouble overriding the background color of a button, whose color is set in some 3rd party CSS.

The (3rd party) styles.css is loaded prior to my checkout.css file:

```
// styles.css

#ac-page #checkoutSteps footer .button {
    background-color: #ea830d;
    border-color: #ea830d #ea830d #a25a09;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

And then in my CSS:

```
// checkout.css

body.checkout-onepage-index #ac-page #checkoutSteps footer .button {
    background-color: #E5582C;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

<div id='ac-page'>
    ...
    <ol class='opc' id='checkoutSteps'>
        <li>
            ...
            <footer id="shipping-buttons-container" class="" style="">
                <button type="button" class="button" title="Proceed To Shipping Type" onclick="shipping.save()">Proceed To Shipping Type</button>
                <span id="shipping-please-wait" class="please-wait" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="../loader.gif" alt="Loading next step..." title="Loading next step..." class="v-middle"> Loading next step...
                </span>
                <p class="required">* Required Fields</p>
            </footer>
        </li>
</div>
```

In every browser except IE9, my checkout.css rule takes precedence, as it is more qualified.  Something I'm doing missing here?

UPDATE:

I tried adding `!important` to the rule and that didn't help.

Also, I should note that there is a border override which *is* working just fine.

Another really odd thing about IE9's "Firebug Lite" which is what I'm using to try to inspect and better understand the order of precedence - is that it's not showing me *anything* from `checkout.css` at all.  I know that some rules from `checkout.css` are taking effect - the border for example - but it doesn't show me any of them in the inspector.

UPDATE 2:

Posted the markup

Comment: What happens if you use !important (note: I'm *not* advocating its use)?

Comment: To be fair, whenever you're fighting with third party CSS and what you're making is _not_ a library or widget itself I'd use `!important` instead of trying to fight it.

Comment: Agreed with above - it's for these edge cases that `!important` was invented. It stinks, but this is what it's for. Also, the term is 'higher specificity', not 'more qualified'.

Comment: Thanks guys.  So, adding `!important` didn't help.

Comment: Why don't you use the same selector? If your style-file is loaded afterwards, it should override the 3rd party one.

Comment: @MichaB, in general it's just because my custom SCSS happens to have a different structure which is a little bit more organized than the 3rd party code.  I didn't make a special effort for it to be different.  I just tried adding a separate rule with exactly the same selector as the 3rd party CSS, and that didn't help either.

Comment: @kalenjordan if adding important didn't help it's not a "specifity" issue. Your CSS is not being applied at all.

Comment: Did you found your style-rule in the delivered css-file? Perhaps you should post the html-markup concerning this button.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, yes, that seems to be what's happening.  I'm surprised this issue hasn't been hit before?  I did some searching and closest I found was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451578/ie9-css-precedence-bug

Comment: @MichaB, yes I did.  I used that rule to set a blue border and red background color - only the blue border took.  The background was ignored.

Comment: Figured it out!  Thanks for your help guys!!!  @BenjaminGruenbaum

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was one of these bad boys in the 3rd party CSS:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFEA830D', endColorstr='#FFEA830D', GradientType=0);
```

Which is a background color gradient.

Putting

```
filter: none;
```

in my `checkout.css` fixed it.